# GCD jumbles the data on scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using grand central dispatcher to load images from server but when i scroll the table the data, i.e. images, jumbles - means 1st image comes to some other place and like wise other images do.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemImageCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    NSDictionary *item=[responseDictionary objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);


    NSString *actionForUser=[item objectForKey:@"action"];



    objc_setAssociatedObject(cell,
                             kIndexPathAssociationKey,
                             indexPath,
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        if([actionForUser isEqualToString:like])
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"user_image"]];
            NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];

            //userProfileimage
            UIButton *userImageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5, 40,40)];
            userImageButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            userImageButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
            [userImageButton setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [userImageButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(userImageButtonclick:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:userImageButton];

        }
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by the time your async method has finished, `cell` has been recycled and used for a different index path, so you're updating the wrong cell.

At the point of update, get the cell reference by using the **tableview's** (not the data source method) `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. This will return the correct cell, or nil if the cell isn't on the screen any more. You can update this cell safely.

You should probably be adding the image data to your model as well so you aren't downloading it repeatedly.

As an example, instead of this line:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:userImageButton];
```

You should have something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cellToUpdate = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cellToUpdate.contentView addSubview:userImageButton];
```

There are further problems with your code; you are not caching the images, you will be adding this subview every time this cell comes on screen, and if the cell is reused for a case where it doesn't need the button, the button will still be present. I have only addressed the "GCD jumbling" as described in your question.

Comment: jrturton as I'm a new comer in this so not getting exactly what u r saying can u plz explain it by codeing.and thnx for the reply

Comment: thnx jrturton i'll try with it.